# charset in mysql json

Tags: php, mysql, json, character-encoding

I have this php script for get the value

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf8_general_ci");
require_once('db.php');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `hebreux`';
$stm = $db->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

When I ran the script I have the value below

**[{"francais":"Bonjour","hebreux":"???","chemin":""},{"francais":"Bonne semaine","hebreux":"???? ???","chemin":""}]**

My question is why I have `???` and not the hebrew text?
in my mysql database I show the hebrew value I have `charset utf8_general_ci` for the hebrew value.

Thank you if you can help me.

Comment: `charset=utf8_general_ci` is not a thing in the context of HTTP.

Comment: what can I do then please thank you

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .  Note:  the question marks were created during `INSERT`, and the Hebrew text is lost.

Answer (score -1):

you shoud adjust 2 sides
one side in your code by setting connection charset
by execute these queries after connection start with your db

```
header("Content-type:application/json;charset=utf8_general_ci");
require_once('db.php');
$sql = 'SET NAMES "UTF8"';
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8' ;
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute()
$sql = "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'" ;
$stm = $db->prepare($sql) ;
$stm->execute()
 

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `hebreux`';
$stm = $db->prepare($query);
$stm->execute();
$rows = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

then your files where you write your code open with any program like Notepad++ that allow you to adjust file Encoding then change all files to **UTF-8-BOM**

You can adjust database  by any way like
If you're using the PDO abstraction layer with PHP ≥ 5.3.6, you can specify charset in the DSN:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:charset=utf8mb4');
```

If you're using mysqli, you can call set_charset():

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');       // object oriented style
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8mb4');  // procedural style
```

If you're stuck with plain mysql but happen to be running PHP ≥ 5.2.3, you can call mysql_set_charset.

If the driver does not provide its own mechanism for setting the connection character set, you may have to issue a query to tell MySQL how your application expects data on the connection to be encoded: SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'.

Comment: Hello thank you for your help is it possible for you to give all script with my script please thank you

Comment: I update my answer , try it but you need to update encoding of files with notepad++

Comment: Really Thank you for your help  Have nice day Akram

Comment: You are welcome Carle

Comment: This is not how you set the connection charset. Please do not spread false information.